# restygwt - get original server error on client site

Tags: java, gwt, resty-gwt

I have an application build on GWT + RestyGWT with Spring

I'm trying to make some user friendly exception handling on client site.

I have some method on server side that throws an exception:

```
@PostMapping(...)
@Transactional(...)
public long withdraw(@PathVariable(value = "amount) long amount) throws CustomException {
    if (amount < 0) {
        throw new CustomException("Amount is negative");
    }
    account.withdraw(amount);
    return account.balance;
}
```

It's called async from client side and handled there:

```
... new MethodCallback<...>() {
@Override
public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable throwable) {
    // here should be error handling
}
```

How can I get original error message and class ("Amount is negative" and CustomException)? All I could get from method and throwable variables were:

- errorCode = 500
- response message = "Internal Server Error"
- throwable is org.fusesource.restygwt.client.FailedResponseException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot receive the same `Exception` in *RestyGWT* (this can be done using *GWT RPC*). But, you can handle exceptions uniformly in the server side (in jersey you can use an exception mapper in spring is called exception handler) and return an error response with a known JSON format. Then you can get this error response using the `FailedResponseException` (this is the exception you are receiving right now), this exception contains the response, so you can do `MyKnownErrorResponse o = JSON.parse(failedResponseException.getResponse().getText())`.